# HTML form submit in proper way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a search field in every section of my webpage . (**www.webpage.com,www.webpage.com/new**) .

When I submit a form in **/new** it does sth like this **www.webpage.com/new?search=example** but I want it to be **www.webpage.com/?search=example** wherever I submit the form .

HTML

```
<form  id="search_form">
  <input id="search_field" type="search" name='search'>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('#search_form').submit();
```

Comment: Add an `action = 'page.php'`, this is where your datas have to be sent and a `method` (GET or POST)

Comment: action="/" is for me , I am using node.js

Answer (score 4):

Specify the base URL with the `action` attribute.

```
<form action="/" ...>
```